# Get order number to pass it to another woocommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a store with woocommerce 3.7.1, which uses sequental order numbers for convenience. Booster makes them sequental. I also have plugin for delivery. 
The problem is that, delivery plugin uses unchanged by booster order number and it is makes confusion. I need to pass to delivery plugin changed order number, and i have some code, but it is not working :((

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_edostavka_order_number', 'my_custom_order_number', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_order_number( $number, $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $result = $order->get_order_number();
    $number = (int) result;
    return $number;
}
```

I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it myself. Here is the working code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_edostavka_order_number', 'my_custom_order_number', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_order_number( $order_id ) {
        $wcj_order_number = get_post_meta( $order_id , '_wcj_order_number', true );
        if( $wcj_order_number )
            $order_id = $wcj_order_number;

        return $order_id;
}
```

Booster stores changed order number in "_wcj_order_number".